# Finding number of days between two dates having format as 'mm/dd/yyyy' in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I am getting random numbers on converting to days

**CODE**

```
$myDateValue = sql::readOne("SELECT `myDateValue` FROM table WHERE id = Value");
// the myDateValue is collected as TEXT in MYSQL

$futureDate =$myDateValue->myDateValue;
$now =time();
$futureDateTimestamp = strtotime($futureDate);

$days = number_format(($futureDateTimestamp - $now)/86400,2,'.',' '); 

echo $days ;
```

This is giving random numbers 
**OUTPUTS**

```
  OUTPUT1:  -14566.25566
  OUTPUT2:  1452.33655
```

Comment: 1. Don't store dates as strings, store them as **dates** 2. What is a valid value for `myDateValue`?

Comment: but still i am using strtotime, myDateValue are future dates as 12/25/2014

Comment: Your code works for me. The odds are some of your date values are not correct. This is a common side effect of storing dates as strings.

Comment: That means, The Datetimepicker is taking values as MM/DD/YYYY , so even if I convert it there to Timestamp, I am getting the same timestamp values, even before putting into database  or converting it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything else is fine, Just add This

```
    $diff = $futureDateTimestamp - $now;
    $days = intval($diff /86400) ;
    // to find the remaining hours
    $rem_sec = $diff % 86400
    $rem_hr = intval ($rem_sec/3600);

<p> You have total of <?php echo $days .'days and'  $rem_hr ?> hours Left  </p>
```